# How to validate api request signature based on timestamp

Tags: php, api, hash

I'm developing API, and 1 of the requirements is similarity to https://developer.hotelbeds.com/docs/read/Home

Their authentication system is

```
Api-Key         Your registered API key
X-Signature     SHA256 encoding signature
```

Signature is generated with this code:

```
$this->signature = hash("sha256", $apiKey.trim($sharedSecret).time());
```

**The question is: How on server side I can validate this signature?**

I've searched their SDK for anything, but `time()` not being sended to server.

**UPDATE:**

Tested API with delay before sending request (signature generated 120 seconds before request), and it still works. Seems like it's using some other algorithms, then cycle for 30 last seconds.

Here is link for gist with test: https://gist.github.com/ineersa/756bcbe70f339afafd7e

**UPDATE 2:**
Tested up a bit further, and it seems that it works in range of 5 minutes. So it must be 600 hashes generation.

Comment: I don’t see how that would be possible, without knowing all of the original input values. (Perhaps they try and generate the hashes for the x last seconds before the current timestamp the request was received at or something … but that would be a rather unusual approach.)

Comment: The time need not to be send to the server. It looks like they are using seconds as the smallest unit (`System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000`). So if a request is older than 1 second it is not valid.

Comment: @CBroe I've thought about it, but with this approach timezones will be a problem.

Comment: No, timezones will of course not be a problem, because the unix timestamp has nothing whatsoever to do with timezones.

Answer (score 0):

First you got to know the api key on the server side somehow.
Then you have to create a loop incrementing a date with seconds starting from some defined period before, like 30 seconds before and each loop you create the hash and compare to the hash you got from client.

limit your loop to the amount of time you want to give in seconds.
for example, if you want to have 60 seconds

```
for($i=-60;$i<=0;$i++){
    $token_validate = hash("sha256", $apiKey.trim($sharedSecret).strtotime(date("YmdHis",strtotime("now {$i} seconds"))));
    if($token_validate==$token_sent){       
        break;
        $somevalidationvar=true;
    }
}
```

All the point is that you got to know that when the key is generated time is gonna be X and when key is validated time is gonna be X+Y. So this way presuming for example that the request can not last longer than 60 seconds you can create the hash assuming each second from 60 seconds before now till now and see if any of the hashes match the one you sent.
If it does you got it.

Comment: Tested up their API with 120 seconds delay, it still works.

Comment: Yes. Updated question. With approach you proposed max limit of time between creating signature and sending request would be 60 seconds.

Comment: hmmm.. can i see the implementation of the verification code?

Comment: oh! I tought you were doing the verification. Now i got your question. You dont want to implement a verification youre just trying to understand theirs..haha but anyway, 5 min of request is not too much depending on the internet required conditions like working on a 2g